# Can you set uBlock to allow Piwik tracking on all sites?

Tags: browser-addons, privacy, adblock

I'd like to reward site owners that use Piwik instead of Google Analytics by allowing Piwik tracking scripts globally. Is there any way to do this with the uBlock extension? So far I only found instructions for allowing/denying based on host.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this:

```
@@/piwik.php
@@/piwik.js
```

to your 'My Filters' tab in the uBlock settings.

This should be sufficient to allow piwik tracking globally on most sites.

Comment: I guess you also need to allow `@@/piwik.js`

Comment: yup, you're right. I've added that to the answer.

Comment: In some case, there are also rules which block anything hosted on piwik subdomains such as `piwik.exmample.com`. In this case you may also want to add `@@piwik.` as rule